# How to dynamically insert text from an external file in a Powerpoint slide?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

My goal is to ensure that the C++ code I insert in my presentation compiles correctly. I therefore thought I'd have each example in a separate file (so that I can compile it), and include the text from those files in the Powerpoint slides...  I want this 'inclusion' to be dynamic, so that if I change the code in a file, the slides are automatically updated.

Is it possible?  Will I have to use LaTeX instead of Powerpoint? Any other suggestion about how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I answered a similar question for openoffice here: http://superuser.com/questions/199624/linked-code-syntax-highlighting-frames-and-captions/211778#211778 maybe this will help. BTW still not sure why he never marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question. You don't need code to get the slide to update if you insert it as an object

[Powerpoint 2007 linking to external content](https://superuser.com/questions/201771/powerpoint-2007-linking-to-external-content)

Answer (score 1):

In PowerPoint you will need to write a macro to read the text and update the slide.

An example of a macro to read a text file can be found here:
[Read in text from an ascii file](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00124.htm).

You will also need to force the slide to refresh:

```
' assuming a reference to the current slide in oSl
ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide(oSl.SlideIndex)
```

This article could also be useful as an example :
[Add a random phrase from a text file to a text box on each slide](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00570.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you rename a *Powerpoint 2010* `.pptx` file into a `.zip` file, you can open it via `Winzip`, `7zip` etc.

The slide contents are written in `XML` files named `"...\ppt\slides\slide2.xml"` in this packed archive structure.

A snippet from a German `.pptx` file:

```
-<a:p>
-<a:r>
<a:rPr lang="de-DE" smtClean="0" err="1" dirty="0"/>
<a:t>A text to change ....</a:t>
</a:r>
-<a:r>
<a:rPr lang="de-DE" smtClean="0" dirty="0"/>
<a:t> </a:t>
</a:r>
-<a:r>
<a:rPr lang="de-DE" smtClean="0" err="1" dirty="0"/>
<a:t>another Text to change</a:t>
</a:r>
-<a:r>
<a:rPr lang="de-DE" smtClean="0" dirty="0"/>
<a:t> </a:t>
</a:r>
-<a:r>
<a:rPr lang="de-DE" smtClean="0" err="1" dirty="0"/>
<a:t>Text ...</a:t>
</a:r>
-<a:r>
<a:rPr lang="de-DE" smtClean="0" dirty="0"/>
<a:t> </a:t>
</a:r>
-<a:r>
<a:rPr lang="de-DE" smtClean="0" err="1" dirty="0"/>
<a:t>Text ...</a:t>
</a:r>
<a:endParaRPr lang="de-DE" smtClean="0" dirty="0"/>
</a:p>
```

So, it should be possible to prepare a `.pptx` template file and replace placeholder strings like `${Text1234}` using a home-grown tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an API which will allow you to code in C++ directly, but there is one for Java: [poi.apache.org](http://poi.apache.org/) so you could always wrap in it in a script to execute it.

That said, LaTex sound like a better fit IMHO.