# Is it possible to set a style to show line continuations in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2008

Sorry if the title is a little unclear. Here's the situation:

I have a bunch of code in a Word document, with a style specifically for code. However, in a few cases it is not clear that a line has been wrapped, and so in these places I have manually added a "↵" glyph to indicate the wrapping.

Would it be possible to make Word do this automatically?

For the sake of clarification: I need this to show in normal document view (not just when non-printable characters are shown) and when the document is printed.

Comment: There is a way to convert source code to images. This way if the source code changes, you can regenerate the image that Word uses. This saves you from duplicated code. See also: http://superuser.com/questions/213217/convert-html-to-image

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will solve your problem.

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+*</kbd> (the last key is an asterisk)