# Import images from folder to PowerPoint Slide Master container

Tags: batch, vba, macros, microsoft-powerpoint, import

I have a folder of 1,500+ jpg images, I need to import them to a specific container in new slides in PowerPoint. The Photo Album tool doesn't have the customization I need. In the past (with less images) I've run a mouse recorder program to insert a new master slide and click the 'New Picture' button for me but this doesn't seem feasible for a project this size.

I need the images to go into the 'Click icon to add picture' container. After I import all of the images I'll be running a script to import cell data from excel into specific text fields on this Slide Master layout (I have this part working).

[image: Slide Master layout]

**Bonus points!**

If the picture can be set to 'Fit' instead of 'Fill' by default that would save a lot of time.

Comment: [How to dynamically insert text from an external file in a Powerpoint slide?](http://superuser.com/questions/155728/how-to-dynamically-insert-text-from-an-external-file-in-a-powerpoint-slide?rq=1).  The homemade tool sounds like your best hope.  It would be semi-trivial to generate an xml file, by looping through each image file in a directory, how trivial that actually is depends on what programming languages your familar with.

Comment: You might be able to use FSO to go through the .jpg folder and if found, add slide and insert jpg

Comment: @Ramhound I looked at your link and tried a couple tests. When I open the PowerPoint zip folder I see a separate XML file for each slide and no clear indication of where it's pulling the image reference from. If there's no guide to generating these XML files I don't think this would be faster than my prior method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

Insert > Album

[image]

Use buttom **File/Disk...**

And press **Create**

Each photo is placed on a slide

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. As I mentioned in my original question the Photo Album tool doesn't allow the customization I need to be effective. The best that will do is fill the slide but I need other information containers on there. Unless you know a way for the Photo Album tool to import images to a specific container from a slide master layout this unfortunately doesn't help me much.

Comment: You need to put special effects or this method you do not mind.
Please explain more

Comment: If there was a way to use this tool but have the images import to a specific position / size this would be perfect but I don't think that option exists.

Comment: Picture Layout setting in there if you need it to not have to use special tools for the job. Like PhotoStage Slideshow Producer

Comment: Apologies if this sounds like advertising, but I have a (commercial) PPT add-in that does pretty much what you're after.  It won't drop the images into a placeholder but it lets you define the location/size with a rectangle and fits the images into that rectangle as large as possible w/o distortion.  It pulls in the names of the image files from your XL spreadsheet (and also can merge in text and other bits from XL).  There's a free, fully functional demo at http://www.pptools.com/merge/

Comment: @SteveRindsberg it's not against the rules as long as you disclose your affiliation. This comment would better belong in an answer showing how to do it.

Comment: @Raystafarian There's a lot of "how to" on the site I linked to and I welcome direct questions from anyone who's trying out the demo; but the rather detailed instructions would only be of interest to someone who *is* trying out the s'ware.  It'd only be a real answer for them, not the general community (and again, I didn't want to appear to be advertising in an answer).  Make sense?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks, Steve! I'll look into using your add-in.